# OWLAPI and HermiT reasoner: non-asserted deleted individuals are still inferred

Tags: java, owl-api, hermit, dlquery

I am currently using OWLAPI jointly with HermiT reasoner and I am experiencing what appears to me as a bug.
I defined several methods that update the ontology and during unit testing I reached several contradictory results.

My methods can add, remove and test the presence of an individual, let it belong to some specific class or let it belong to `owl:Thing`.

Here's an example of contradiction: a removed individual is still present as an instance of `owl:Thing`.

```java
boolean added = ontology.addIndividualToClass("Person", login);
Assert.isTrue(added, "The individual must be present.");
ontology.think();

boolean exists = ontology.doesIndividualBelongToClass("Person", login);
Assert.isTrue(exists, "The individual must be found.");

boolean removed = ontology.removeIndividualFromClass("Person", login);
Assert.isTrue(removed, "The individual must be removed.");
ontology.think();

// The next assertions is satisfied.
exists = ontology.doesIndividualBelongToClass("Person", login);
Assert.isTrue(!exists, "The individual must not be found.");

// The next assertions will fire, interrupting the test.
exists = ontology.doesIndividualExist(login);
Assert.isTrue(!exists, "The individual must not be present.");
```

My methods operate in this way:

1. the add method generates a new class assertion,
2. the remove method finds and removes the corresponding class assertion in case it exist,
3. finally, the test method checks both inferred and asserted individuals for name and possibly class.

All methods seem to operate correctly, but when an existing individual is removed it still appears as inferred. The method `think()` is basically the wrapping of `flush()` and forces the ontology to apply all pending changes. I am using HermiT in buffering mode and I noticed that switching to non-buffering does not solve the problem.

```java
public boolean addIndividualToClass(String className, String login) {
    [...]  // Checks on parameters.
    OWLNamedIndividual individual = dataFactory.getOWLNamedIndividual(individualName, prefixManager);
    if (individual == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not get named individual.");
    OWLClassAssertionAxiom classAssertion = dataFactory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(clazz, individual);
    ChangeApplied changed = ontology.add(classAssertion);
    return changed.equals(ChangeApplied.SUCCESSFULLY) || changed.equals(ChangeApplied.NO_OPERATION);
}
```

```java
public boolean removeIndividualFromClass(String clazz, String individualName) { 
    [...] // Checks on parameters.
    Optional<OWLClassAssertionAxiom> individualAssertionOpt =
            ontology
                    .getClassAssertionAxioms(clazz)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(
                            i -> i.getIndividual().asOWLNamedIndividual().getIRI().getRemainder().orElse("").matches(individualName)
                    )
                    .findFirst();

    if (!individualAssertionOpt.isPresent())
        return false;
    else {
        ChangeApplied changed = ontology.remove(individualAssertionOpt.get());

        return changed.equals(ChangeApplied.SUCCESSFULLY) || changed.equals(ChangeApplied.NO_OPERATION);
    }
}
```

I am experiencing problems with the following two methods:

```java
public boolean doesIndividualBelongToClass(String className, String name) {
    [...] // Parameters tests and retrieval of 'clazz'.
    Set<OWLNamedIndividual> inferredIndividuals =
            reasoner
                    .getInstances(clazz, false)
                    .getFlattened()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(i -> i.getIRI().getRemainder().orElse("").equals(name))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    Set<OWLNamedIndividual> assertedIndividuals = ontology
            .individualsInSignature()
            .filter(i -> i.getIRI().getRemainder().orElse("").equals(name))
            .filter(
                    i -> reasoner
                            .getTypes(i)
                            .entities()
                            .filter(t -> t.getIRI().getRemainder().orElse("").equals(className))
                            .findFirst()
                            .isPresent()
            ).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    inferredIndividuals.addAll(assertedIndividuals);

    return inferredIndividuals
            .stream()
            .findFirst()
            .isPresent();
}
```

```java
public boolean doesIndividualExist(String login)  {
    return doesIndividualBelongToClass("owl:Thing", login);
}
```

Once an individual has been removed `doesIndividualExist()` returns true, where `doesIndividualBelongToClass()` returns false. During debugging I noticed that removed individuals are still present as instances of the `owl:Thing` class.

I double checked and started asking DL queries through the method `resoner.isSatisfiable()`:
the DL query `{X}` where `X` is a deleted individual name turns out to be satisfiable.

I made another test: I saved the ontology, browsed it with Protege and found that deleted individuals where not present, *neither inferred*.

Is someone aware of a workaround or an actual solution?
Am I missing something?

Comment: If you can share the whole code and create an issue in the HermiT project (in the OWLCS organisation, it's a sibling project of OWLAPI on GitHub) it might be easier to replicate and investigate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OWLReasoner instances can be buffering or non buffering - HermiT reasoners can be created with either setting.
A buffering reasoner will see changes you make to the ontology but not apply these changes to its internal models until you call the flush() method on it. A non buffering reasoner will apply changes to its internal models immediately.

To confirm if this is the reason behind your issues, please show how you create the OWLReasoner instance. OWLReasonerFactory has methods for creating both buffering and non buffering reasoners.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is my initialization method:
```java
manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
ontology = manager.createOntology(IRI.create([REDACTED]));

iri = ontology.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get();
prefixManager = new DefaultPrefixManager(iri + "#");

reasonFactory = new ReasonerFactory();
reasoner = reasonFactory.createReasoner(ontology);
dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
```

Comment: As it can be seen by my snippet I create a non-buffering reasoner.

Comment: @Chaos reasonFactory.createReasoner() creates a *buffering* reasoner. reasonFactory.createNonBufferingReasoner() is the one you need.

Comment: Apologies I intended to say *buffering* and I already stated in my question I use the 'flush()' method to force the reasoner to consider possible updates. It is wrapped inside the the 'think()' method that also measures the reasoning time.